# Define Explicit Inheritance For Base Abstract Method

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

In C#, you can explicitly define a function implemented from an interface. The function will then be only accessible through that interface, allowing you do define another method in the derived class with the same name and parameters, but differing return types. Take the following example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void DoSomething();
}
public class Bar : IFoo
{
    void IFoo.DoSomething()
        => throw new NotImplementedException("Ha ha! Tricked you! I don't do anything!");
    int DoSomething()
        => throw new Exception("I tricked you again! I do do something! I throw exceptions!");
}
```

However, what if I have an abstract class?

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}
```

How would I do the same thing in this case? The following attempt, for instance, throws a build error.

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
    override void DoSomething()
        => throw new NotImplementedException("Ha ha! Tricked you! I don't do anything!");
    public int DoSomething()
        => throw new Exception("I tricked you again! I do do something! I throw exceptions!");
}
```

Bear in mind that in a real use case, I would also put fields in the abstract class, not just methods. So just rewriting the base class as an interface is not an option.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a single class. If you introduce an intermediate base class between `Foo` and `Bar`, you can override `DoSomething` there, then shadow it with `new` in `Bar`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Derp, sorry - my VS Error List was empty so I assumed the compiler was happy with it - when I did an explicit rebuild it gave me the CS0111 error, so cheerfully withdrawn :)

Comment: This is technically possible in bare hand-written IL, but C# does not allow it.